# How to access a certain field inside Nested Documents

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON FILE

```
{
  "_id": "GgCRguT8Ky8e4zxqF",
  "services": {
    "notifications": [
      {
        "_id": "5hqPb76VhiwJ7Y86q5",
        "work": true,
        "maried": true
      },
      {
        "_id": "4ds4d654sd65d7zW45",
        "work": false,
        "married": true
      }
    ],
    "profile": {
      "name": "Janis"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get the object inside the notification array  but couldn't figure out how to do it

exemple:
Is there a way to do it with a function by entering the _id : 4ds4d654sd65d7zW45 
i want to get this

```
{
  "_id": "4ds4d654sd65d7zW45",
  "work": false,
  "married": true
}
```

Couldn't figure out how to access the notifications and get what i want by entering the id

Could you please help me ?

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.find()` inside the function:

**USING ES6**

```js
var obj = {
  "_id": "GgCRguT8Ky8e4zxqF",
  "services": {
    "notifications": [{
        "_id": "5hqPb76VhiwJ7Y86q5",
        "work": true,
        "maried": true
      },
      {
        "_id": "4ds4d654sd65d7zW45",
        "work": false,
        "married": true
      }
    ],
    "profile": {
      "name": "Janis"
    }
  }
}

function findObj(id) {
  return obj.services.notifications.find(({_id}) => _id === id);
}
console.log(findObj('4ds4d654sd65d7zW45'));
```

**USING PLAIN FUNCTION (works for older browsers and IE)**

```js
var obj = {
  "_id": "GgCRguT8Ky8e4zxqF",
  "services": {
    "notifications": [{
        "_id": "5hqPb76VhiwJ7Y86q5",
        "work": true,
        "maried": true
      },
      {
        "_id": "4ds4d654sd65d7zW45",
        "work": false,
        "married": true
      }
    ],
    "profile": {
      "name": "Janis"
    }
  }
}

function findObj(id) {
  return obj.services.notifications.find(function(obj){
    return obj._id === id;
  });
}
console.log(findObj('4ds4d654sd65d7zW45'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use `Array.prototype.find` method.

```
const json = {
  "_id": "GgCRguT8Ky8e4zxqF",
  "services": {
    "notifications": [
      {
        "_id": "5hqPb76VhiwJ7Y86q5",
        "work": true,
        "maried": true
      },
      {
        "_id": "4ds4d654sd65d7zW45",
        "work": false,
        "married": true
      }
    ],
    "profile": {
      "name": "Janis"
    }
  }
};

function getNotificationById(json, id) {
  return json.services.notifications.find(n => n._id === id);
}

getNotificationById(json, '4ds4d654sd65d7zW45');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` function of `Array` for this.

```js
var data = {
    "_id": "GgCRguT8Ky8e4zxqF",
    "services": {
        "notifications": [{
                "_id": "5hqPb76VhiwJ7Y86q5",
                "work": true,
                "maried": true
            },
            {
                "_id": "4ds4d654sd65d7zW45",
                "work": false,
                "married": true
            }
        ],
        "profile": {
            "name": "Janis"
        }
    }
}

function getNotificationById(id) {
    return data.services.notifications.filter(({
        _id
    }) => _id == id)[0]
}

console.log(getNotificationById("4ds4d654sd65d7zW45"));
```